# Incomplete bokeh plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe of 10 columns and trying to get bar plot using Bokeh.
The HTML file has the complete plot when I use plot_width=10000. 
However when I increase the plot width(so that there is space between x axes values) to 30000, the plot does not fill beyond 2010. Here is the complete code. Please suggest the way forward.

```
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis6 as palette
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,FactorRange,HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect,send_file
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file,save
from bokeh.embed import components,file_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.layouts import row,column
from bokeh.core.properties import value


dates = pd.date_range('20050101', periods=3900)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3900, 10), index=dates, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))






s = df.resample('M').mean().stack()
s.index = [s.index.get_level_values(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),s.index.get_level_values(1)]

x = s.index.values

l1=list(s.index.levels[1])


counts = s.values

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=250,plot_width=30000, title='Plotting data',
   toolbar_location=None, tools="")


p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=1, source=source, line_color="white")

p.y_range.start = s.values.min()
p.y_range.end = s.values.max()
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.01
p.y_range.range_padding = 0.01
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

output_file('test_plot.html')

save([p])

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me with Bokeh 1.0.4 and OSX/Safari. I suspect this is a limitation/issue with the underlying HTML Canvas implementation in whatever browser you are using, in which case there is nothing we can do about it. The only suggestions I can make are to split the plot up into smaller subplots, or use a different browser (or possibly different version of the same browser)

Comment: What amuses me is that the x axis values are plotted till the end  but not the y axis values.